# Ansible dynamic inventory GCP filter flattened

Tags: filter, ansible

As mentioned in [parameter/filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_info_module.html), that also points out [this link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)

> By default the filter expression operates on root level resources. In order to filter on a nested list(not at the root level of the json) , one can use the `--flatten` flag to provide a the `resource-key` to list. For example, To list members under `my-project` that have an editor role, one can run:
>
> ```sh
> gcloud projects get-iam-policy cloudsdktest --flatten=bindings --filter=bindings.role:roles/editor --format='value(bindings.members)'
> ```

I'm trying to filter out only hosts that have size 50 (`diskSizeGb: "50"`) using dynamic inventory filter only.

Could someone point out how to use flatten tag with Ansible dynamic inventory since I cannot access nested values when running the following (I'm not even sure if that's possible):

```sh
ansible-inventory -i name.gcp.yml --list
```

This is an example output of what I want my filter to be based on:

```
"disks": [
    {
        "boot": true,
        "deviceName": "somename",
        "diskSizeGb": "50",
    }
],
```

These are the filters I have tried but I'm getting Invalid list filter expression as a warning and I'm not getting the expected result:

```yaml
filters: (name eq hostname) (disks[0].diskSizeGb eq '50')

filters: [name=hostname AND disks[0].diskSizeGb=50]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [the first documentation page you are referring to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_instance_info_module.html), emphasis mine, this parameter is:

> **A list** of filter value pairs. Available filters are listed here https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters.
> **Each additional filter in the list will be added as an AND condition** (filter1 and filter2).

So your filter have to be a list:

```yaml
filters:
  - name = hostname
  - disks[0].diskSizeGb = 50
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @B.enoit.Be. I tried your suggestion. However, I'm getting the same result and warning as the other two filters I tried previously. The issue looks like is the [0] not being recognized in the dynamic inventory filter as it is in ansible playbooks.